# Android getActionBar().subtitle Changing Color

Tags: android, android-actionbar

With this code:

```
getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#CFCAF3")));
```

I can change the action bar's color.

But I want to change the subTitle's color.

```
getActionBar().setSubtitle("Tarih 2 Mayıs 2015");
```

But it's gray. See the image below

[image]

But in this application it's black

[image]

How can I change the subTitle's color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Manifest, create a theme for the activity. An example is given below.

```
<activity
  android:name="com.x.y.Mainact"
  android:theme="@style/ActionBarTest"
```

In your theme ActionBarTest,

```
<style name="ActionBarTest" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/OverFlow</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/black</item>
 </style>
```

The item

> textColorSecondary

is what does the trick for us.

Comment: on Manifest:
<application
...
...
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


And on Styles.xml
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/deneme</item>
    </style>
with this code,it's worked.Thanks

Comment: This changes the secondary text color for the whole activity not just the action bar.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define it in your style. Assuming you are using a AppCompat theme style

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTheme.ActionBarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="subtitleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="textColor">@color/red</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Assuming you are using AppCompat theme style you need to get rid of those `android` prefixes before `actionBarStyle` and `subtitleTextStyle` ;)

Comment: Thank you, forgot to remove.